# Adding event listeners in JavaScript functional components

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I am making a webpage using vanilla javascript components and I can't get event listeners on components to work, the code below throws an error "function statement requires a name". I tried without the ${}, only onclick="onClick", but that throws an error saying onClick is not defined. What would be the correct way of doing this?
Thank you.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const onClick = () => {
    document.querySelector('#navbar').style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
  };

  const template = `
    <i id="nav-opener" class="fas fa-bars" onclick="${onClick}"></i>
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#!" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!" target="_blank">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!"target="_blank">Portfolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `;

  return template;
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like you're just generating an HTML string here, you should set the onclick property to a string of the JavaScript expression you want to execute. If you've defined the function somewhere else on the page in the global scope, you could call it with `onclick="myClickHandler()"`. Notice that the function is executed with '()'. You could also just write the body of that function into the string, such as:

```
<i onclick="document.querySelector('#navbar').style.transform = 'translateX(0)';">
```

It looks like you're missing text content inside the `<i>` tag, so it might be difficult to click on it the way you have it written and see the result.

Comment: why cant i define the function i want to call inside the scope of the function I am calling it in? its like in react when i have an onChange funtion defined inside the scope of my component and call it in its return value

Comment: React is a framework that has its own ways of taking JSX synatx and converting it to a DOM tree. It looks like you're just using a function to return a string representing HTML. Strings have no scope, they're just strings, so you will have to write out whatever JS syntax you want literally into your string template.